# Is there a way to get parenthesis from an array, and then put all the elements in them into an array

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to take an array say:

`["(",89,"+",8,")","*",92]`

and get a new array with

`["(",89,"+",8,")"]`

I have tried to do stuff like

```
for (i=myarr.indexOf("(");i<myarr.indexOf(")");i++) {
  otherarr.push(i)
}
```

It didn't seem to work, and other solutions involve just messing around with that. I couldn't seem to get it to work

Comment: Can there be multiple parenthesis?

Comment: "Yes, it is". And that's probably not the answer you want, so [edit your post to be a good question](/help/how-to-ask) please. Remember that this is not a general help forum, you are expected to put some work into your question, and right now there is no sign that you've done any [searching and researching](/help/how-to-ask) first.

Comment: Ok I have edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on minimal criteria given you can use `slice()` with start index at the index of the `(` and end index one past the `)`.

This is only based on the very simple case you have shown and does not consider any nested `()`

```js
const arr=["(",89,"+",8,")","*",92],
res = arr.slice(arr.indexOf('('), arr.indexOf(')') + 1 );

console.log(JSON.stringify(res))
```

Comment: I feel dumb now, but I completly forgot the slice, and when I was doing my research I kept getting stuff similar to that I had lol